# I'm looking for a good book with examples on Differential Manifolds

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology

I would like to know if there is a good book about differentiable manifolds that give examples about definitions and practice application of the theorems.

Like, determining one partition of unity for the $n$-sphere and something like that about other definitions.

Comment: I personally like [Lee's book](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/).